# Looking for CAD files of basic crystal structures

Tags: 3d-models

I'm looking for basic models of crystal chemical structures. The most basic example would be a cube, it gets harder though as I next need polyhedrons with one of three angles < 90°, then two, etc.

Is there a database of these out there somewhere? Or is the fastest way to make them myself?

Answer (score 5):

You may find that [OpenSCAD regular polyhedron library](https://github.com/benjamin-edward-morgan/openscad-polyhedra) may serve your requirements.

[image: regular polyhedra library image]

From the linked site:
All polyhedra are centered at the origin and have an edge length of 1.
From the linked site:

Included polyhedra:

```
tetrahedron
octahedron
hexahedron
icosahedron
dodecahedron
cubeoctahedron
truncated_tetrahedron
snub_cube
rhombicuboctahedron
truncated_hexahedron
truncated_octahedron
icosidodecahedron
snub_dodecahedron
rhombicosidodecahedron
truncated_cuboctahedron
truncated_icosahedron
truncated_dodecahedron
truncated_icosidodecahedron
```

OpenSCAD is a reasonably easy "description coding" program at the base level. I suspect that for something such as this, it might not qualify for the easy reference.

My search also linked up a few Thingiverse entries, but they weren't as sophisticated as the above and may be a subset of the library link.

Comment: Agreed. OpenSCAD is the way to go. There are plenty of crystal and polyhedral libraries for it available online.